# wordpress apache ルーティングがおかしい

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

仮想環境にwordpressをインストールして試しています。
ファイル構成は/var/www/html/wordpress直下にwp-adminなどが入っています。
php-fpm eventMPM構成でPHPを動かしています。

**httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/
<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress/">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

この状況で、以下の左のアドレスでアクセスすると、->の右のアドレスに代わり、:の右の結果になります。

IP -> IP　: Testing 123... Apacheの画面
IP/index.php -> IP : Testing 123...
IP/tekitou -> IP/tekitou　:表示できる（サイトトップ）
IP/wp-admin/edit.php -> IP/wp-admin/edit.php : 接続できる(編集画面)

.htaccessを見るとindex.phpだろうがtekitouだろうがindex.phpにアクセスされるようにしか見えませんが、なぜこうなるかがわかりません。
IPでトップ画面を表示する方法とIP/index.phpでURLをIPにしてトップ画面を表示する方法をご教示頂ければ幸いです。

httpd.conf 有効行のみ抜粋

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wordpress/"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: 確かに記載のhtaccessだけであれば問題なさそうです。ということは別の原因の可能性があります。ApacheTestページの画面が出ているということは、何かしらエラーログは発生していないですか？またhttpdの設定で見逃していそうなところはないですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。error_logを一度消してIPだけでアクセスしてみましたが、エラーは出力されませんでした。sudo vi /var/log/httpd/error_log　　httpd.confの有効行だけ抜粋したものを上に載せます。

Answer (score 1):

DirectoryIndexが抜けていたようです。

<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php